# Windows 2008r2 OS/2 Warp4 Share

Tags: windows, sharing, os2

got here an os/2 Warp4 . From windows 2008r2 I can mount the share with
net use x: \os2\sharename

after this I see that the HDD is 1.1GB big , from that 420MB is used

but if I try to double click on the mounted share I get an error :

The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: and you googled the error no doubt, and then what happened? Also you could include what errors you get from the command line when CDing to the share and trying to create a file on  it by eg `echo adfsdfs>a.a`

Comment: I did google .
so net use h: \\os2\share
then
h:\
dir

OUTPUT : Volume in Drive H is AR
Volume Serial Number is 1873-14D6
Directory of H:\
File Not Found

Strange ...
seems like the Directory Listing is not working
I can mkdir robert
cd robert and it works
but even though I created robert on root , I cannot see it with dir
seems like the directory/file listing is not working somehow

Comment: so mkdir and rmdir both work ... so I can access the share ... but for some reason I cannot view its contents... this only happens from Windows 2008r2 , Windows 7 , Windows 10 . On Windows 2003, Windows XP it works